# I want to get result for all employees

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have the following code, but I don't get the true result.
I'm getting only the result for one employee, and what I want is for all employees in my tables.

The code is:

```
Select * From
     (Select EmpNo, EmpEName 
      from EmployeeMainFile 
      Group By EmpNo, EmpEName) s2
  INNER Join 
     (Select DISTINCT EmpSNo,EmpSTotalSalary 
      from EmpSalary where ID = 
          (Select Max(ID) from EmpSalary) 
           Group by EmpSNo,EmpSTotalSalary) s1
    on s1.EmpSNo = s2.EmpNo
```

Comment: Provide sample input and expected output....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the subquery expression `Select Max(ID) from EmpSalary` only returns one ID for the entire set of salaries.  You need the Max(ID) for each Employee.

If `ID`s are sequentially increasing, and greatest value of `ID` (for each Employee) represents the latest, current, salary for that employee, then:

```
Select e.EmpNo, e.EmpEName, Max(EmpSTotalSalary) MaxSalary
From EmployeeMainFile e
    Join EmpSalary s
       on s.EmpSNo = e.EmpNo
          and s.ID = (Select Max(ID) 
                    from EmpSalary 
                    Where EmpSNo = s.EmpSNo)
Group By e.EmpNo, e.EmpEName
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So how can i get for all Employees?

Comment: Ok i'm getting answer but for one employee there is more than one salary, so if Employee "ABC" has salary 500 and its id is "1" and another salary 300 and its id is "2", i want to get the 300 not 500, i want the result based on ID

Comment: How can same employee have two different `ID`s?  What is `ID` the`ID` of, exactly ?

Comment: i got Ambiguous column name 'ID'. in the EmpSalary the keys are ID and EmpSNo. so i can have more than an ID for one employee

Comment: Solved. Perfect. Thank youuu a loottttt.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * From
     (Select EmpNo, EmpEName 
      from EmployeeMainFile 
      Group By EmpNo, EmpEName) s2
  INNER Join 
     (Select EmpSNo,Max(EmpSTotalSalary) from EmpSalary 
           Group by EmpSNo) s1
    on s1.EmpSNo = s2.EmpNo
```

**UPDATED ANSWER**

```
Select * From
     (Select EmpNo, EmpEName 
      from EmployeeMainFile 
      Group By EmpNo, EmpEName) as s2
  INNER Join 
     (
      SELECT * FROM 
      (
      Select EmpSNo,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY EmpSNo ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC) as Latest
      from EmpSalary 
       ) AS ABC
       WHERE ABC.Latest =1 ) as s1
    on s1.EmpSNo = s2.EmpNo
```

Comment: im getting this error: Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: i got for one employee several salaries, i want to get on record for each employee. for example if Employee "ABC" has salary 500 and its id is "1" and another salary 300 and its id is "2", i want to get the 300 not 500, i want the result based on ID

Comment: Now i got one record for each employee, but i get the highest salary for each, i want if ID for Salary 500 is "1" and Salary 300 is "2" i want to get the 300 not 500

Comment: what do you mean by that? ID:1 and ID:2 are two different employee not the same one, that is why they are all returned with the `max(salary)` they have

Comment: if you want to filter out record which empid is equal to 1, add this `WHERE EmpNo !=1` to the end

Comment: yes but for each employee may have more than salary (Because i want to keep Salary history), but what i want to get is the last salary entered in the table. i have ID column in the table so i can get it based on this column

Comment: ok, then you cannot use `MAX` function, do you have timestamp column in table to tell which one is the latest one?

Comment: In EmployeeMainFile i have: ID,EmpNo,EmpEName... and in EmpSalary i have ID,EmpSNo,EmpSTotalSalary

Comment: Check my updated answer to see whether it gives you all the employee with the latest salary

Comment: So how could you tell which one is the latest salary? If you have timestamp column to identify the latest salary, replace the `TIMESTAMP` with the column name in my updated answer

Comment: What is the timestamp, sorry im new to this

Comment: no worries, timestamp is like a column for storing the date or datetime type value, do you have such a column in your table could tell which is the latest salary entered for that Employee?

Comment: I got your point. No i don't have, but it is a good idea. Thank you.

Comment: well, If my guess is correct, you do... `ID` is sequentially increasing so it is a valid determinant for the latest Salary.